# Laravel API + React SPA, http only cookies not setting

Tags: reactjs

I Have a react SPA that will consume a Laravel RESTful API, using a stateless token system fetched by AXIOS in the platform.

The requests alike, are firing as I would expect and they are returning the responses with a response cookie with the JWT however they are not being saved in the browser.

The stack is build using Vagrant to serve the API and create-react-app to serve the platform.

I have setup the hosts correctly and they are as below.

api.domain.com is my api and the platform is domain.com

I will happly display some code but Im unsure where the problem lies.

What are things I could check to find out why the cookie is not saving in the applcation tab / cookies

When the cookie is returned from the API it has the set cookie header

```
Set-Cookie: token=eyJpdiI6IllEb2JGWFdyVDVqZWVlYXhnSHp6SVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0JicmpNSk5xK1B2U1Frd2N4VkhFUFh2XC9jcmtXNktBeDM5U2dcLzlaU2ZoS0JCYXd4TnRWUlpnbktpQXMyM0tkeFU1ckE1a0tYN3B2dHlmMDRUNkVzVys0MWZZb2hEN0xsXC9cLzBheHhrK1ZkaFNicmRPM2hJc0RtaWduNm5vMGJRTVMycjhBdzAzRFwvMUpFcmk0Q3pVd29ZcFpEYkdNeVNYelwvMmh5dm93ZVg5VlRDTDZzTkRYbDl0b0FjQmZMQnA0OW9SZGRhXC83VDRIbmJkaDVyQ2Z3NXFzQ2JuUnFyXC80T0JyY3g0Q1g4V0VnZFJXY1FWcTJ4TFJNSTRnWFVWdHZxMm1cL1ExZDdBNUJsRVZWZER2UUUxTXdiRVFSQnhVNlRnQzg3Zjg4ZUtYdGxPWjMyN1lsOE9SNFgrR3J4N3gwOExxU3RDU1ZnUjFna08xSVdIcUQyZ0hnZ0pvQ1J0cTFCdjAzd0I0XC84K0RmQjFlWVpZWlM3TkdIZzE5WHVUUmZPYWdHTDRPT2VrNW9WN0hIWFFFUEc4b3UwRXBEcFpEMmpHcmYwUGo0Y2V4RmlNSzd5UDgwMGlzZXplSVg1dDZwV3BURGNhemk1eERoNzd3bFM3YTVDcjk0MkpIZlB2bGJ1QStzVG9XODBCaHVcLzJockNmRVwvNUdtSW5HbkY0alVDT2ZJaXZwWWJcL1M2SFFadXRlRXh5UHFmYmVyZVUxRXFNbDFjODdXZ05CYjJuc1pCb1l5Wll4V25MKzdzV1wvaUtaYVVxOEoyOWNiZ0pscHRyWmExTXJsaWdPRGdyMVhCTDlLNTlLd2x6WTRZVllGQVIyS296UDUzRlVPWGFUZkpndkxcL3hrQ0tRUFVKYmtSTTR0MmFvV25mRkl0cWhBOUpMTkJjcmsrdytsY3ZrTUlSWlVFdDVVamNHRDA5KzVNYUtBbmFVVjdZR2tyaUMwZjVhRGtuV0dBRVpXU3JscWpOeTBUb3FnNEdrc2lvNU1xeStPSldYYk1QeGMyOFhTNXY0aDhBMkxVVFZzMERIUXNEdEhnUGdZYmdNY25aT0Q2YmNuWGZlenY5UUk0eFBzbEtpclwvU1N3SlNRaDNFSmpUMW5XS2czV2luaGV5ekxVWkpQdHdkY3pZam9EXC82dHhUOXRyZnRGOE91aEdNMWZVZz0iLCJtYWMiOiIwMmJmMjI0YjM5YTVkNGU0OTNhMzQ4NWYwMmQ4ZWM5YjJmMGE1ZGIxZjU4ZTI3NmU4MDNlOTRmNjkwMjk0YzhkIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 14-Dec-2019 15:03:37 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.domain.com; httponly
```

but this is never saved in the cookies for this page.